# Executing a shell script on a udev rule

Tags: java, linux, shell, udev

I am trying to execute a Java program on inserting a USB Flash Drive and pass the path of the USB Flash Drive as a parameter to my Java program. To achieve this, I have written a 'udev' rule in both '/etc/udev/rules.d' and '/lib/udev/rules.d' with the names '99-thumbdrive.rules' and '98-thumbdrive.rules'.

The rule is as follows:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN="/home/nouman/Data/NSProj/shell.sh"
```

The 'shell.sh' file has been made executable by using 'sudo chmod +x shell.sh'

When I insert my Flash Drive and run the command 'udevadm test /dev/bus/003/008', I see my rules being read.

```
read rules file: /lib/udev/rules.d/98-thumbdrive.rules
read rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-thumbdrive.rules
```

My shell.sh file is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
java USB
```

I have been trying this for a couple of days now and have read most of the posts online but am unable to run my script. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Your script depends on being run from a working directory, so the problem might not be that it is not run but that running it fails because udev doesn't run it from that directory. Assuming that the `USB.class` is in the same directory as the script, does it work if you put `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` before the `java USB` line?

Comment: Using `$0` isn't guaranteed to be portable see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028 for details/etc.

Comment: @Wintermute just tried your suggestion, still no good

Comment: Unless "java" is in your PATH, prefix it with the full pathname. - Add a suitable -cp x option to the java call: x should contain the directory containing  the USB class file. And: is class USB in the default package?

Comment: @Wintermute I had been playing around with the code and after multiple attempts I am able to run my script on USB insertion. But my script is still not able to run a Java program. I checked if my script is running by using 'mkdir new' and on usb insertion a folder 'new' is created.

Comment: See [this answer on Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99073/29510). +1 for laune.